# Google geocoding api not working in Android mobile applications, while it is working on system in ripple

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, cordova, google-api

I'm new to the field of mobile application development (apache cordova).

I'm facing a problem with google geocoding api while developing a weather application. The code is working fine on my system but it is not working on the android devices.

I couldn't fetch the json result object in my android phone while retrieving latitude and longitude with the pin code of any location.

Can someone help me out, if there is any process for debugging to figure out where the error is!?

The following is the query string that I've used to get the coordinates of a location.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=50001&sensor=true

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the change I've made in the meta tag, where I've mentioned the source from where I'm pulling out the data from..

The following is the default meta tag that comes up with the creation of new project in apache cordova (in index.html).

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="* 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

And the following is the modified meta tag in index.html where we need to mention about the api source where we get the data from.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="* 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com https://query.yahooapis.com https://maps.googleapis.com https://api.openweathermap.org/ 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

Comment: I think you are missing "default-src" from your `content="..."` e.g. `content="default-src *..." `

Comment: Hi Simon. Instead of default-src, I've used * which means we can use inline scripting too.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging, the Chrome remote debugger / inspection tools are excellent and will allow you to see the JS console on the device as well as inspect the web view in the Cordova application as if it were any other web page.

To use these, you'll need the developer / remote USB debugging turned on on your Android device, and to have it connected to your computer via a USB cable.  Then Chrome should be able to see it as a remote inspectable web view.

Details on setting up Chrome remote debugger can be [found here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en).

It's likely that your actual problem is with the Content Security Policy / whitelisting plugin.  By default the Content Security Policy meta tag in your index.html (created by Cordova CLI in Cordova 5 or higher) will not allow remote Ajax requests... you can configure it to allow connections to a set of servers you want to connect to using the connect-src clause, or use * to allow any connection.  It's probably best to explicitly list the sources you want to connect to in the interests of security.

To do this, add something like this to your index.html in the `<head>` element:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src http://maps.googleapis.com">
```

Which will enable Ajax for maps.googleapis.com.  There's a comprehensive blog post discussing Content Security Policy [here](http://moduscreate.com/cordova-5-ios-9-security-policy-changes/).

Comment: Hello Simon. Thanks a ton. Your point made my day and it was in the meta tag itself where we need to make changes. I figured out the fault.